# Why a Samsung J3 wont call/text but data works

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-j3

A friend and I own the Samsung J3 model phone.  Both phones shared this exact problem within a day or two.

The issue was the phone could not call or text.  Neither incoming nor outgoing attempts were successful.  The kicker was the internet still worked without WiFi.  Any outgoing call failed saying there wasn't service.

The problem was resolved by manually switching a setting in 'mobile networks'.  Taking it off the network and putting it back on after a few minutes.

I'm wondering why this would happen to both phones in short time, and why changing that setting solved it.  Maybe the phone had an update that causes a glitch in that area?

Any ideas are welcomed.

Edit: wanted to also add the LTE data was on and operating with no Wi-Fi being used.

Comment: were you on LTE?

Comment: Yes and the LTE speed was weirdly faster than normal.  That may or may not be connected but I did take notice

Comment: Maybe the problem was that your network was not switching to GSM or WCDMA from LTE when you tried making call. Though calls in LTE can be made over VoLTE which I guess is not provided by your carrier.

Comment: Thank you for responding but I think i could have worded differently.  Why would two J3 phones with different carriers do exact same thing days apart?  Maybe a glitched phone update or something?

Comment: Indeed. Generally all smartphones automatically switch to different network mode when call is made while LTE is on, unless you have forced to [**LTE only**](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/01/force-2g-3g-lte-only-mode-in-android.html).